# Place jquery cookie for age disclaimer

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have downloaded jquery cookie.  I want to place a cookie when the user agrees they are over 21 so the next time they visit the site it does not ask until it expires.  Would appreciate any help with the code for that as I have no experience with cookies and it's about time being that I code sites for a living.. smh.  Thank you ahead of time.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Must Be 21 Years Old to Enter">Are you 21 years old?</div>


<script>  
$( "#dialog" ).dialog ({ 
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 410
});

$("#dialog").dialog ({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
  buttons: {
    'Yes, I am 21 years old!': function() {
     /*cookie code here!!!*/
       $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    },
    'No, I am not 21 years old.': function() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com",
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need jQuery to set cookies as DOM API's provides its own method to do it.

```
document.cookie="newCookie=value";
```

And in your case,

```
$("#dialog").dialog ({
dialogClass: "no-close",
buttons: {
    'Yes, I am 21 years old!': function() {
       document.cookies = "ageConfirm=true";
       $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    },
    'No, I am not 21 years old.': function() {
        document.cookies = "ageConfirm=";
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com",
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

You can also use [js-cookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), which is lightweight JS plugin for all the cookie operations.

Comment: Actually, `document.cookie` is part of the DOM API. It's not part of JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottMarcus my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Hahaha I'm an idiot.  I meant I downloaded java script cookie not jquery :/...  Thank you so much I will use the DOM API.  That looks very simple to implement.

Comment: @Edge Happy to help!

Comment: How long does a cookie have by default before it expires? Maybe you could show me the syntax for setting the expiration date as well?  Thanks!

Comment: I know how to set a certain date like so: document.cookies = "ageConfirm=true"; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT"; but is there a way to set a certain amount of time instead of a specific date?

Answer (score 1):

Just use document.cookie = "ageConfirm=1";

To check your cookie has been set you can use the Application > Storage tab in google developer tools. http://prntscr.com/foz7lh

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir! I  Love good references. Sometimes hard to find in the sea of bad ones.